# How do I build a simple Docker container that can run an HTML page with Vue JS code?

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, virtual-environment

If I run the code in Webstorm or Xampp, it works as intended. But I wanted to build a Docker container where i can run and develop my code.

The files in question are:

**vue.js**:

```js
'use strict';

Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            worker: new Worker('./scripts/primeWorker.js'),
            firstPrime: 2,
            cache: null,
            started: false,
            running: false,
            ended: true,
            drawing: false,
            styles: {SLEEK: 'sleek', STUNNING: 'stunning', DEFAULT: 'default'},
            v_style: 'default',
        };
    }, methods: {
        startDraw() {
            const color = {
                'r': ~~(Math.random() * 255),
                'g': ~~(Math.random() * 255),
                'b': ~~(Math.random() * 255),
            };
            this.ctx.fillStyle = this.ctx.strokeStyle = `rgb(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b})`;

            this.drawing = true;
        }, stopDraw() {
            this.drawing = false;
        }, doDraw(e) {
            if (!this.drawing) return;

            this.ctx.beginPath();

            const posX = e.clientX - this.$refs.draw.offsetLeft;
            const posY = e.clientY - this.$refs.draw.offsetTop;

            this.ctx.arc(posX, posY, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            this.ctx.fill();
            this.ctx.closePath();
        }, // region value setters
        toggleRun() {
            this.running = !this.running;
        }, cachePrime() {
            this.cache = parseInt(this.$refs.suffering.innerHTML);
        }, setPauseButton(text) {
            this.$refs.pauseButton.innerHTML = text.toString();
        }, endMySuffering(pain) {
            this.$refs.suffering.innerHTML = pain;
        }, // endregion
        startPrimes() {
            if (!this.ended || this.started) return;

            this.started = true;
            this.running = true;
            this.ended = false;
            this.worker.postMessage(this.cache);
        }, pausePrimes() {
            if (!this.started || this.ended) return;

            this.toggleRun();

            if (this.running) {
                this.worker.postMessage(this.cache);
                this.setPauseButton('Pause');
                return;
            }

            this.resetWorker();
            this.cachePrime();
            this.setPauseButton('Continue');
        }, resetPrimes() {
            if (!this.started) return;
            if (!this.ended) {
                if (this.running) this.cachePrime();

                this.endMySuffering(`<strong>Your beautiful prime is:</strong> ${this.cache}`);
                this.resetWorker();
                this.cache = this.firstPrime;
                this.ended = true;
                this.running = false;
                this.setPauseButton('Pause');
                this.$refs.stopButton.innerHTML = 'Reset';
                return;
            }

            this.started = false;
            this.endMySuffering('<em>How could you?! :\'(</em>');
            this.$refs.stopButton.innerHTML = 'Stop';
        }, resetWorker() {
            this.worker.terminate();
            this.worker = new Worker('./scripts/primeWorker.js');
            this.worker.onmessage = this.workerResponse;
        }, workerResponse(e) {
            this.endMySuffering(e.data);
        }, toggle(style) {
            this.v_style = style;
        },
    }, mounted() {
        this.cache = this.firstPrime;
        this.worker.onmessage = this.workerResponse;

        this.ctx = this.$refs.draw.getContext('2d');
        let img = document.createElement('img');

        img.onload = () => {
            this.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 300);
        };
        img.src = './resources/logo.png';
    },
}).mount('#app');
```

**index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HYP Canvas & WebWorker Example</title>
    <!-- vue.global.prod.js is just the file that enables me to write vue code -->
    <script src="lib/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
    <style>
        .sleek {
            color: blueviolet;
            background: whitesmoke;
            font-family: "Segoe UI", serif;
        }

        .stunning {
            color: darkgreen;
            font-family: Cambria, serif;
            background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
        }

        .default {
        }

        #app > label > span {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #app > canvas {
            border: solid black 4px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HYP3 Lab2 Example</h1>
<div id="app">
    <p>Draw me a smiley!</p>
    <canvas width="400" height="300" ref="draw"
            @mousedown="startDraw"
            @mouseup="stopDraw"
            @mouseleave="stopDraw"
            @mousemove="doDraw"></canvas>
    <br><br>
    <label v-bind:class="[v_style]">Play around with primes:<br><br>
        <span v-bind:class="[v_style]" ref="suffering"><em>No prime in sight... :(</em></span><br><br>
        <button @click="startPrimes">Start</button>
        <button @click="pausePrimes" ref="pauseButton">Pause</button>
        <button @click="resetPrimes" ref="stopButton">Stop</button>
    </label>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="style in styles">
            <button @click="toggle(style)">{{ style }}</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<p style="font-size:small">
    Hypermedia Systems & Architecture<br>
</p>
<script src="scripts/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  vue-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: vue_app
    volumes:
      - .:/Docker_Container
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - vue-network
networks:
  vue-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm install -g http-server

WORKDIR .

VOLUME .

RUN npm install

# I don't know how to write a build.sh, so here's where the error occurs:
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

The furthest I got was being able to render `index.html` with a make-shift `server.js` file, but `index.html` didn't read the JavaScript / Vue code. My current Docker setup is missing a `build` script for `node` and I don't know how to build one, let alone approach this problem.

Comment: "*A few weeks later, I feel like I know even less now than at the beginning.*" - You are in the [valley of despair (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_Effect_01.svg) - keep pushing, and you will overcome it. --- Please [edit] the post and share your `docker-compose.yml`  and `Dockerfile`(s).

Comment: check `https://github.com/antfu/vitesse/blob/main/Dockerfile`

Comment: `npm run build` tuns `package.json/scripts/build`. Generally somethig like `vite build`, `webpack build` or whatever. You don;t have a build step, so you odn;t need that